# Regular expression to check 0 , 00 , 000 , 0000 , 00.00

Tags: java, regex

I want check that a strings does not contain value 0. That is, strings like

```
 0 ,  00 ,00.00
```

are not allowed, but it should allow field like

```
10.00 , 11.01, 0.12
```

In short I want to check currency string . It should not enter 0 value.

please suggest me regular expression for this.

I tried `"^0$"` but it failed on 10 or 10.90 something like that ..

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself.  If you want strings only containing 0, then 10.00 is not allowed.  Please review/rewrite your question to clearly explain what you're after.

Comment: I really don't understand this question at all

Comment: Could you please edit this post and elaborate with sample input and expected output , So that we can help you out

Comment: Do you mean `a string should have at least one zero`?

Comment: I would parse the string and see if its is equal to 0 if that is what you want e.g. "-0.0e-1" is 0.

Comment: Is that `I want to match string only have 0`; Are these okay? `0, 0, 0` or `0, 00` or `0, 1` or `-0.0, 0e10`

Comment: I've edited the question to ask what user ask in comments and later edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears that you want to match all fields that contain at least one zero.  If so, you can use pretty much the simplest regex possible:

```
"0"
```

Update: so, you want to reject anything that only contains zeroes (but it might have spaces, commas, and periods as well.  Ok, this will fail to match any "only zero" string:

```
[^0,\.\s]
```

Comment: nope ..It should not like I have string sometime 0 or some time 00.00 or 00000 it not fixed size ,but one thing is clear that if whole string have only 0 no any number then it will reject.

Hope you will get my question.

Comment: @Satyam, updated; I think I understand what you want now.

Comment: @Satyam, if you get errors you may have an issue with double-quoted strings.  You may need to double each backslash.

Comment: may be your answer is true .I am not sure but while using this into java . Facing issue of syntax error.. I am going accept your question please make sure .Thank

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern uses anchors. `^` means match at the start of the string and `$` means match at the end. Therefore your pattern only validates a sting that is only a single 0. If any value that contains a zero is valid, you could simply remove these anchor characters. Therefore any string that contains a 0 will return true.